# Stop refresh modaless popup on button click if already open up

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have page where I'am opens a modaless popup on a button click `Open Popup`.

**Scenario:**

Initially when page opens up no popup is displaying, I click on button `Open Popup`, my modaless popup is opens up and I have filled some data on that popup and if I click again on "Open Popup" button of parent page then my popup gets refreshed.

**Expected:**

If my modaless popup is already open then on click on `Open Popup` button (of parent) instead of refresing the popup, focus should comes on already opened popup.

I'm trying to achieve this using **jQuery** or **JavaScript**.

**What I have tried so far:**
On click on `Open Popup`, I'm trying to check if open popup has 'in' class then do not open popup like:

```
if ($('#NewPopup').hasClass('in')) {
                return false;
            }
```

But, this is not working. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you dont want to allow the user to click the pop button if the pop is already opened, in that case, ideally disable the parent page by masking it through some transparent div using z-index. Doing so user won't be able to click on the button and hence you dont have to do all this checking :)

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest solution, but this is not required by my customer he wants to click on button even if popup is already open.

Comment: Anyway I have found the solution, posed below. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution which checks if jQuery dialog is already open or not.

Here I am checking if dialog is already opens up then do not open it again:

```
if (!$('.ui-dialog-content').dialog("isOpen")) {
            $("#" + options.id).dialog("open");
}
```